# "@xmartlabs/react-native-line": "^2.2.0",'RNLine-Swift.h' file not found

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

```
  "@xmartlabs/react-native-line": "^2.2.0",
```

```
  "react-native": "0.72.6",
```

platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '13.4'

pod 'LineSDKSwift', '~> 5.0'

I tried to connect line login react native using

@xmartlabs/react-native-line I got error at AppDelegate.mm file. 'RNLine-Swift.h' file not found

Answer (score 0):

remove `pod 'LineSDKSwift', '~> 5.0'` from your pod file and run pod install.
It may fix your problem.

Comment: please help this issue is still unresolved. can you please share the appdelegate configuration